# wxPython get colour of panel

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to retrieve the background colour of a panel in wxPython

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Panel colour')
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(panel)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        print(self.GetBackgroundColour())
        print(panel.GetBackgroundColour())

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        lbl_description = wx.StaticText(self, label='Hello world')
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(lbl_description, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

but the output I get is

```
(225, 225, 225, 255)
(225, 225, 225, 255)
```

Clearly, I am doing something wrong. How should I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers gives you the colour as [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) values.

[image]

RGB colours are defined by three values for Red, Green and Blue going from 0 to 255. The fourth  values is the alpha value (transparency).

Comment: Thanks Joaquin. I understand the numbers, but in my case they give white and that is not the true colour of the panel

Comment: The panel in your image is grey, 225,225,225 is grey

Comment: You are SOOOO right. I read it as (255, 255, 255). I really am dyslexic